# Position Image based on Browser Width and Height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was wondering if there was anyway I could position an image based on the browser's width and height within a HTML file. I know if I wanted to change an image's width/height, I could do something like this:

```
<script>                                                   
    alert("Width is " + window.outerWidth + " height is " + window.outerHeight);
    var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];                   
    canvas.width = 200;                                                       
  </script>
```

Is there anything similar I can do for positioning an image at a specific location, based on the browser width and height. Ideally, a way that does not include media queries if possible!

Thanks!!

Comment: My apologies, I forgot earlier. It has been done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To position an image based on the browser's width and height, give it an `id` to target it in CSS. Then use that `id` to give it an absolute position, and use the `vw` and `vh` units to position it. Each `1vw` is 1% of the window's width, and each `1vh` is 1% of the window's height:

HTML:

```
<img id="myImg" src="http://i.imgur.com/5LGqY2p.jpg?1">
```

CSS:

```
#myImg {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20vw;
    top: 10vh;
}
```

In this example, the top left corner of your image will be 20% of the way from the left of the screen, and 10% of the way down from the top of the screen.

---

Read more about CSS units here: https://css-tricks.com/the-lengths-of-css/